# How to structure IF condition in MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am trying to write a MySQL trigger. I have two tables like this:

```
Table A------------------------------Table B

order_id--------sku---------------order_id----order_#----sku_copy

    568---------AAA---------------568---------2345
    567---------BBB---------------567---------6789-------empty column
    566---------CCC---------------566---------1234
```

When a customer makes a purchase a new record is added to each table. I have added column ‘sku_copy’ to Table B, so it does not get populated when a new record is created.

When a new record is created, I want my trigger to copy the ‘sku’  field in Table A to the ‘sku_copy’ field in Table B. However, the problem I am having is how to structure the following condition in the trigger.

IF: ‘order_id’ in Table A matches ‘order_id’ in Table B. THEN: copy ‘sku’ from that Table A record to the record in Table B with the matching ‘order_id’. The data should be added to Table B ‘sku_copy'.

I am using the following SQL trigger but it gives this error when it's run:

"#1363 - There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger"

Here is the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    AFTER INSERT ON tableA
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    INSERT INTO tableB
    SET sku_copy = OLD.sku,
         order_id = OLD.order_id,
        order = OLD.order;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Can some one show me how to correct the error in this code or suggest a better one?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Here is an update:

I tried this trigger (this is the live data instead of simplified as in the above examples) but get an error code:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE virtuemart_order_id=new.virtuemart_order_id; END IF; END' at line 7"

Here is that trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `sku_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `uau3h_virtuemart_order_items` 
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF (old.order_item_sku_copy != new.order_item_sku)
    THEN
    UPDATE uau3h_virtuemart_orders
        SET order_item_sku_copy=new.order_item_sku,                      
    WHERE virtuemart_order_id=new.virtuemart_order_id;
    END IF;
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this trigger work?

Comment: There is no `OLD` record when inserting something new.  Have you tried `NEW` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you will value TableB first as it contains the order_no. In that case you need to use an update statement in your trigger instead of an insert statement:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56574/1)

**MySQL 5.6.6 m9 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(order_id INT, sku VARCHAR(10));

CREATE TABLE TableB(order_id INT, order_no VARCHAR(10),sku_copy VARCHAR(10));

GO
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    AFTER INSERT ON TableA
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE TableB
    SET sku_copy = NEW.sku
    WHERE order_id = NEW.order_id;
END;
GO
INSERT INTO TableB(order_id, order_no)VALUES(1,'111');
INSERT INTO TableB(order_id, order_no)VALUES(2,'222');
INSERT INTO TableB(order_id, order_no)VALUES(3,'333');
GO
INSERT INTO TableA(order_id, sku)VALUES(1,'AAA'),(2,'BBB');
```

(The `GO` in this example is used as a batch separator and not send to MySQL.)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56574/1/0)**:

```
| ORDER_ID | ORDER_NO | SKU_COPY |
----------------------------------
|        1 |      111 |      AAA |
|        2 |      222 |      BBB |
|        3 |      333 |   (null) |
```

If you also want to react to updates, just create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56574/1)

**MySQL 5.6.6 m9 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(order_id INT, sku VARCHAR(10));

CREATE TABLE TableB(order_id INT, order_no VARCHAR(10),sku_copy VARCHAR(10));

GO
CREATE TRIGGER TableA_AfterInsert
    AFTER INSERT ON TableA
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE TableB
    SET sku_copy = NEW.sku
    WHERE order_id = NEW.order_id;
END;
GO
INSERT INTO TableB(order_id, order_no)VALUES(1,'111');
INSERT INTO TableB(order_id, order_no)VALUES(2,'222');
INSERT INTO TableB(order_id, order_no)VALUES(3,'333');
GO
INSERT INTO TableA(order_id, sku)VALUES(1,'AAA'),(2,'BBB');
GO
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TableA_AfterUpdate
    AFTER UPDATE ON TableA
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF (OLD.sku != NEW.sku)
    THEN
      UPDATE TableB
      SET sku_copy = NEW.sku
      WHERE order_id = NEW.order_id;
    END IF;
END;
GO
UPDATE TableA
  SET sku = 'NEW'
WHERE order_id = 2;
GO
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56574/1/0)**:

```
| ORDER_ID | ORDER_NO | SKU_COPY |
----------------------------------
|        1 |      111 |      AAA |
|        2 |      222 |      NEW |
|        3 |      333 |   (null) |
```

In both cases the `NEW` and `OLD` virtual tables refer to the table the trigger is defined on. `NEW` contains the new version of the row that was inserted or changed. `OLD` contains the pre-change version of the row. `OLD` is only defined in an update trigger as there is no old version on an insert.

Comment: Hello Sebastian - Thank you very much for responding. It will take me until tomorrow to digest and apply your post, as it is late here. I will post my results here. Again, thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Hi Sebastian - Useing your examples I have successfully created the trigger. Here is the version that is working:

Comment: DELIMITER $$

 CREATE TRIGGER sku_AfterInsert
    AFTER INSERT ON uau3h_virtuemart_order_items
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE uau3h_virtuemart_orders
    SET order_item_sku_copy = NEW.order_item_sku
    WHERE virtuemart_order_id = NEW.virtuemart_order_id;
 END$$;

 DELIMITER ;

Comment: Great news. Glad I could help. Would you mind marking the question as solved then?  (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I want to say this forum is much more user friendly than some others I have tried. Instead of asking me why I would want to do something like this, you gave me the examples that allowed me to construct the trigger. I learned much from this post. Muchas gracias amigo!